# Saindo do foreach JQery

Tags: javascript, jquery, front-end

Estou tendo dificuldade de sair de um foreach quando a condição do if interno ser atendida, segui as recomendações da documentação oficial do JQuery que diz para dar um `return false` porém continua não funcionando, segue o codigo usado:

```
if (digitado != "") {
    hashModens.forEach(function (item, i) {
        if ((digitado == item.Nome || digitado == item.Node || digitado == item.Mac) && item.MarkerVisible) {
            let infoPosition = { lat: item.Latitude + 0.000008, lng: item.Longitude }

            retornou = true;
            map.setZoom(22);
            map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(item.Latitude, item.Longitude));
            item.InfoWindow.setPosition(infoPosition);
            item.InfoWindow.open(map);
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Está faltando algo, para que eu possa interromper este foreach?

Comment: Não existe o método forEach no jQuery, acho que você confundiu [`$.each`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) do jQuery com o [`Array.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) do Javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O método [`Array.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) é do javascript, você deve ter se confundido com o [`$.each`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) do jQuery.

Você pode usar jQuery:

```js
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

$.each(array, (i, num) => {
    console.log(num)
    if (num > 5) return false
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Ou usar um `for`:

```js
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

for(let i=0, l=array.length ; i<l ; i++) {
  console.log(array[i])
  if (array[i] > 5) break
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Não é possível para um foreach, mas você tem outras alternativas, como por exemplo utilizando a função [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every), ao retornar true, ele continua, ao retornar false ele para:

```
hashModens.every(function(item, i) {

  if (Sua_condicao){
     return false;
  } 
  return true;
})
```

Comment: Caramba que legal este metodo eu nao conhecia, porem estou usando um Map() e parece que ele só existe em arrays :/

Comment: Sim, para objetos `jQuery` você precisa usar o `$.each` como na resposta do @fernandosavio.